# Excel SUMPRODUCT with blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm using SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIFS but when there are blank cells it show error. my formula is:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((O16:O63="Low")/COUNTIFS(O16:O63,O16:O63,I16:I63,I16:I63))
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to count how many cells got the value `Low` divided by total cells? Can you give some details? input and expected output?

Comment: I want to count how many "Low" I have in "O16:O63" for unique id in "I16:I63" without counting duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O2:O16="Low")/COUNTIFS(O2:O16,O2:O16&"",I2:I16,I2:I16&""))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the bold parts in your formula shouldn't be ranges, they must be criteria.

=SUMPRODUCT((O16:O63="Low")/COUNTIFS(O16:O63,**O16:O63**,I16:I63,**I16:I63**))

Comment: That's not true. This syntax will return an array of results, and is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Excel 365, then you can try combining `COUNT` and `UNIQUE`:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(IF(O16:O23="Low",I16:I23)))
```

[image]

The inner `IF` formula will return `{1;FALSE;3;4;1;FALSE;FALSE;4}`. `UNIQUE` will convert this array into an array of unique values: `{1;FALSE;3;4}`. `COUNT` will finally count how many cells in this range contain numbers (3).

Comment: I have Excel 2016

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the #DIV/0 errors with IFERROR in an array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((O16:O63="Low")/COUNTIFS(O16:O63,O16:O63,I16:I63,I16:I63),0))
```

Comment: the result show "TRUE", not counting number

Comment: You must have done something wrong then. There is no way for that formula to return True.